# Problem injecting Session Bean into PermissionEvaluator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a setup for detailed authorization where I get a session bean to check if a user is logged in. This however do not seem to work, as the session bean become null, even if doing the same way have worked fine in other classes.
I want to access a Session Bean in the follow class:

```
package spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.session;

import org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.DenyAllPermissionEvaluator;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Resource;


public class SessionAuthentication implements PermissionEvaluator{
    
    @Resource(name = "returnSession")
    Session session;
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        System.out.println("evaluating lower");
        if(this.session == null || this.session.getUser() == null){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        System.out.println("evaluating even lower");
        if(this.session == null || this.session.getUser() == null){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

This work totally fine in "normal" classes, so what do I do wrong here?
The Beans are initiated here:

```
package spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.session;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;



@Configuration
public class SessionConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Session returnSession() {
        return new Session();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally were able to solve this after being inspired by some Googling. It do indeed seem that getting the session bean from the SessionAuthentication class that implement the permissionEvaluator does not work.

However, what did work was injecting the session bean into the class that created the class with the permissionEvaluator interface like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SessionSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Resource(name = "returnSession")
    Session mainsession;
    
    @Override  
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = 
          new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new SessionAuthentication(this.mainsession));
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

And then changing the code from above to this:

```
public class SessionAuthentication implements PermissionEvaluator{
    
    private Session session;
    
    public SessionAuthentication(Session session){
        this.session = session;
    }
```

And this works totally fine.